# Migrate deployments and services from stable/nginx-ingress to kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to migrate our ingress controllers from the old stable/nginx-ingress to the newer kubernetes/ingress-nginx

I have followed their instructions for zero downtime deployments.

1. Create a second nginx-controller with the kubernetes/ingress-nginx helm chart.

   - The instanceClassName has to be different than the original.
   - original instanceClassName: nginx
   - new      instanceClassName: nginx2
2. Update dns to point to the new nginx 2 ELB.
3. Get rid of the old nginx-controller

This is all great, but all of our services/deployments are attached to instanceClassName: nginx.  We can update the DNS, but then the services attached to it won't receive traffic.  We can update the services at the same time, but they update at different times.  This will cause an outage of some type while updating.

All of the research I have done seems to stop at that controller level.  It doesn't go deeper and explain how to keep all the services connected during the switch.

How can I get both nginx controllers to route traffic to the application at the same time?  I have not been able to get that to happen at the service or nginx controller level.

Or maybe I'm thinking about incorrectly, and it can work in a different way.

thanks.

Comment: I hope the provided solution helped you and would be happy to assist if you have any further queries. Also please upvote/accept for a wider audience.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods and I have given below with Istio and providing alternate method documentations for your reference.

You can avoid down time while migrating via splitting the traffic. There are few traffic splitting tools. Kubernetes has traffic splitting in-built feature with Istio and it will help you to direct a percentage of traffic to the new ingress controller while keeping the rest of the traffic on the old ingress controller.

Install Istio in your cluster and configure your ingress resources to use Istio gateway instead of the ingress controllers directly.

- Install Istio in your cluster.
- Configure your ingress resources to use the Istio gateway.
- Create virtual service for your ingress resources and gradually increase the traffic to the new ingress controller and also make sure to update your DNS records to point to the new ingress controllers IP.

Reference and for further information please check the official [Istio page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/) and [Istio Service Mesh Workshop](https://www.istioworkshop.io/09-traffic-management/03-traffic-splitting/).

For alternative methods please refer below options:

[Canary Deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#canary-deployments) and [Type Loadbalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#canary-deployments)